# CASE WHEN index usage in SQL Server: seek vs scan

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

Given the following schema:

```
create table dbo.SomeTable 
(
    ID int primary key identity(1, 1),
    SomeColumn varchar(50)
);

create index IX_SomeColumn on dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn);
```

And populate it with some data:

```
declare @i int = 1000;

while @i > 0 begin
    set @i = @i - 1;

    insert dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn) 
    values (convert(varchar, @i))
end
```

This query performs an index seek:

```
select ID 
from dbo.SomeTable 
where SomeColumn = '431'
```

While this query performs an index scan:

```
select ID 
from dbo.SomeTable 
where case when SomeColumn = '431' then 1 else 0 end = 1
```

Is there a way to make the latter (or something equivalent) perform an index seek instead?

I'm asking because I want to be able to put the `case when` into the select list of a view and use it in a `where` clause, but it will never perform as well as the raw form if I can't get SQL Server to do an index seek.

Comment: Your second query is not SARGEBLE. It has no way to know the value of the `CASE` statement until it is applied to every row in the table. That's why you get a scan. Of course it's obvious that the `CASE` statement will only return 1 if `SomeColumn = '431'`, but SQL Server does not look deep enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the execution plan for both queries the seek predicate is very different.

When you do not use a CASE expression in the where clause, the seek predicate leaves the Column alone (does not have to do any calculations on column values) and just do a seek on the index to find the value on the other side of the `=`.

[image]

On the other hand when you use a CASE expression in the where clause, things change a lot , now the seek predicate has parameterized the where clause on both sides of the Where expression. In simple words SQL server does not no what value will be yield for `CASE WHEN [TEST_DB].[dbo].[SomeTable].[SomeColumn] = [@1] THEN [@2] ELSE [@3] END = CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[@4],0)` until it has actually been executed hence using the available indexes option goes out of the window and SQL server ends up doing a scan.

[image]

**Moral of the story**

Avoid using CASE expression in the where clause.

Comment: The auto parameterisation can easily be prevented by adding a redundant comparison of two literal constants. There is just no logic in the optimiser to reverse engineer such expressions and try and make them sargable.

Comment: @MartinSmith wow this is cool trick , just tested it and yes it did remove the parameterization, but would love to know why this behavior ?

Comment: Because if it parameterises the literal values that can prevent other optimisations. E.g if you do `where 1=0` it can evaluate at compile time no rows will be returned and avoid accessing the table at all. If the 1 and 0 are replaced by parameters it can't do that.

Answer (score 6):

The only way you could get a seek there would be by making the `case when SomeColumn = '431' then 1 else 0 end` expression a computed column and indexing the computed column.

You should then find that the expression is matched to the computed column allowing a seek (at the expense of maintaining an extra index).

(If you encounter problems with auto paremeterisation preventing a match adding a redundant `1=1` will prevent this. [SQL Fiddle with plan showing a seek](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d29f4/2))